# Jetstack cert-manager hashicorp vault issuer certificate revocation

Tags: cert-manager

I have setup an issuer for Cert manager that uses hashicorp vault as a PKI backend. What I find curious is that the issuer contains path to the signing endpoint:

```
spec:
  vault:
    server: http://vault.ns:8200
    path: pki/sign/endpoint
```

however I do not see any way to configure CRL endpoint. The documentation states:

Besides creation, these certificates can be **revoked** and removed.
I am quite clear on the creation and removal part, however how does one actually revoke certificates? The CA and Self Signed issuers both provide a configuration for CRL endpoint, but this is not the case for Vault.

Thank you!